# RGB value for Red is showing blue color

Tags: python, rgb

I am creating circles using this code:

```
CENTER = (int((x+x2)/2), int((y+y2)/2))

cv2.circle(img, CENTER, 17, (255,0,0), -1)
```

I took RGB values for red from this site: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

255,0,0 is a standard value for red but the resultant image is showing blue
[image]

Edit: I managed to get this much :

[image]

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread("foot.png")


 for i in range(0,32):





        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        CENTER = (int((x+x2)/2), int((y+y2)/2))
        cv2.circle(img, CENTER, 17, (255,0,0), -1)
```

How do I get them all to be red? Even if I put conversion to RGB before loop it prints same result

Comment: OpenCV reads image in `BGR` format, not `RGB`.

Comment: So what is your *question*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel edited

Answer (score 0):

Remove completely the line:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Wherever you want red, specify `(0,0,255)`.